# Application Crash on loading fragment

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments

When trying to replace a placeholder container with a fragment, my application promptly crashes.

My method to load in the fragment is simply:

```
private void loadFragment(Fragment fragment) {
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragHolder, 
fragment).commit();
}
```

Which I am simply calling as so:

```
Fragment fragment = new MyFragment();
loadFragment(fragment);
```

The container, fragHolder, which I am replacing is a FrameLayout, which is inside a horizontal LinearLayout. Is it possible you can you only place fragments into certain containers?

Based on sources around the web there seems to be nothing wrong with how I'm loading my fragment.

Please ask for more info if required.

Edit:

Error output from LogCat for myapp:

```
   03-17 03:38:02.758 3179-3179/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
03-17 03:38:03.049 1530-2967/system_process E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da
03-17 03:38:03.049 1530-2967/system_process E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008cdf
03-17 03:38:03.049 1530-2967/system_process E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008824
03-17 03:38:03.146 1530-2967/system_process E/OpenGLRenderer: Corrupted GPU pixel buffer
03-17 03:38:05.505 3190-3190/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                 Process: mycompany.myname.myapp, PID: 3190
                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{mycompany.myname.myapp/mycompany.myname.myapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: mycompany.myname.myapp.MainActivity@285a72d1 must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
                                                  Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: mycompany.myname.myapp.MainActivity@285a72d1 must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener
                                                     at mycompany.myname.myapp.MyFragment.onAttach(MyFragment.java:83)
                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1231)
                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransition.addToFirstInLastOut(FragmentTransition.java:1085)
                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransition.calculateFragments(FragmentTransition.java:976)
                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransition.startTransitions(FragmentTransition.java:95)
                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2146)
                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2103)
                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2013)
                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:388)
                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:607)
                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:178)
                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1220)
                                                     at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5953)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278) 
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221) 
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899) 
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694) 
03-17 03:38:05.811 1530-1912/system_process E/ActivityManager: Invalid thumbnail dimensions: 504x504
03-17 03:38:05.877 1530-2967/system_process E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da
03-17 03:38:05.878 1530-2967/system_process E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008cdf
03-17 03:38:05.878 1530-2967/system_process E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008824
03-17 03:38:05.926 1530-2967/system_process E/OpenGLRenderer: Corrupted GPU pixel buffer
03-17 03:38:18.278 3445-3445/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
03-17 03:38:18.278 3445-3445/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
03-17 03:38:18.698 3465-3465/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
03-17 03:38:18.698 3465-3465/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
03-17 03:38:19.178 3482-3482/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
03-17 03:38:19.178 3482-3482/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
03-17 03:38:22.537 3497-3497/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
03-17 03:38:22.537 3497-3497/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
03-17 03:38:22.891 1530-2967/system_process E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da
03-17 03:38:22.891 1530-2967/system_process E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008cdf
03-17 03:38:22.891 1530-2967/system_process E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008824
03-17 03:38:22.963 1530-2967/system_process E/OpenGLRenderer: Corrupted GPU pixel buffer
03-17 03:38:26.068 3508-3508/mycompany.myname.myapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                      Process: mycompany.myname.myapp, PID: 3508
                                                                                      java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{mycompany.myname.myapp/mycompany.myname.myapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: mycompany.myname.myapp.MainActivity@285a72d1 must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
                                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
                                                                                       Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: mycompany.myname.myapp.MainActivity@285a72d1 must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener
                                                                                          at mycompany.myname.myapp.MyFragment.onAttach(MyFragment.java:83)
                                                                                          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1231)
                                                                                          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransition.addToFirstInLastOut(FragmentTransition.java:1085)
                                                                                          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransition.calculateFragments(FragmentTransition.java:976)
                                                                                          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransition.startTransitions(FragmentTransition.java:95)
                                                                                          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2146)
                                                                                          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2103)
                                                                                          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2013)
                                                                                          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:388)
                                                                                          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:607)
                                                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:178)
                                                                                          at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1220)
                                                                                          at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5953)
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360) 
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144) 
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278) 
                                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221) 
                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899) 
                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694) 
03-17 03:38:26.373 1530-1718/system_process E/ActivityManager: Invalid thumbnail dimensions: 504x504
03-17 03:38:26.427 1530-2967/system_process E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da
03-17 03:38:26.428 1530-2967/system_process E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008cdf
03-17 03:38:26.428 1530-2967/system_process E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008824
03-17 03:38:26.487 1530-2967/system_process E/OpenGLRenderer: Corrupted GPU pixel buffer
03-17 03:39:00.025 1638-2034/com.android.systemui E/OpenGLRenderer: Corrupted GPU pixel buffer
03-17 03:39:33.922 2611-2628/com.google.android.gms.unstable E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da
03-17 03:39:33.922 2611-2628/com.google.android.gms.unstable E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008cdf
03-17 03:39:33.922 2611-2628/com.google.android.gms.unstable E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008824
03-17 03:39:33.968 2611-2628/com.google.android.gms.unstable E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da
03-17 03:39:33.968 2611-2628/com.google.android.gms.unstable E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008cdf
03-17 03:39:33.968 2611-2628/com.google.android.gms.unstable E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008824
03-17 03:40:00.025 1638-2034/com.android.systemui E/OpenGLRenderer: Corrupted GPU pixel buffer
03-17 03:41:00.026 1638-2034/com.android.systemui E/OpenGLRenderer: Corrupted GPU pixel buffer
03-17 03:41:33.885 2611-2628/com.google.android.gms.unstable E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da
03-17 03:41:33.886 2611-2628/com.google.android.gms.unstable E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008cdf
03-17 03:41:33.886 2611-2628/com.google.android.gms.unstable E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008824
03-17 03:41:33.933 2611-2628/com.google.android.gms.unstable E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da
03-17 03:41:33.933 2611-2628/com.google.android.gms.unstable E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008cdf
03-17 03:41:33.933 2611-2628/com.google.android.gms.unstable E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008824
03-17 03:42:00.027 1638-2034/com.android.systemui E/OpenGLRenderer: Corrupted GPU pixel buffer
03-17 03:43:26.673 8147-8147/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
03-17 03:43:26.673 8147-8147/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
03-17 03:45:00.033 1638-2034/com.android.systemui E/OpenGLRenderer: Corrupted GPU pixel buffer
03-17 03:45:34.116 2611-2630/com.google.android.gms.unstable E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da
03-17 03:45:34.116 2611-2630/com.google.android.gms.unstable E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008cdf
03-17 03:45:34.116 2611-2630/com.google.android.gms.unstable E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008824
03-17 03:45:34.159 2611-2630/com.google.android.gms.unstable E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da
03-17 03:45:34.159 2611-2630/com.google.android.gms.unstable E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008cdf
03-17 03:45:34.159 2611-2630/com.google.android.gms.unstable E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008824
03-17 03:46:00.028 1638-2034/com.android.systemui E/OpenGLRenderer: Corrupted GPU pixel buffer
```

There is much more before, but SO wont allow me to post it all, I assume there are so many as I am running an emulator? I've selected what appears relevant to me, but don't hesitate to ask for anything specific.

Comment: share **logcat** errors during crash

Comment: @ヅfix Please see update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make your activity Implements `OnFragmentInteractionListener` for example,

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements  YourFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener
{
.
.
@Override
public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) {

}
}
```

implement the methods provided by `OnFragmentInteractionListener` in your activity as well

Comment: On my main activity? 
When I go to implement I only have the option of implementing Myfragment1.OnFragmentInteractionListener, MyFragment2.OnFragmentInteractionListener, etc.

Comment: Do I have to implement this for every single fragment individually?

Comment: `OnFragmentInteractionListener` is a default callback implementation done for activity - fragment interaction, for fragments you want to interact with your activity you will need this, else remove the interface and all references to it inside the fragment

Comment: always happy to help!